# I don't know how to use $ eq and $ regex in the same statement on Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find on my mongodb using $eq and $regex but i can't get it to work,

`db.orders.find({"customer_cod": {$eq: "C00001"}},{"creation_date" : {$regex : "2019"}});`

My idea is to find every orders of one customer on the indicated year. I am familiar with sql but using nosql ... If i use it if I use it separately each statement it works.

If anyone could help me.

Comment: ```> db.orders.find({"customer_cod": {$eq: "C00001"}},{"creation_date" : {$regex : /2019/}});
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Unsupported projection option: creation_date: { $regex: /2019/ }",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong

```
db.orders.find(
   { "customer_cod": { $eq: "C00001" } },
   { "creation_date": { $regex: /2019/ } }
)
```

means

```
db.orders.find(
   { <query> },
   { <projection> }
)
```

Do you store values in `creation_date` field as proper `Date` object? If yes, then your query would be this:

```
db.collection.find({
   $expr: {
      $and: [
         { customer_cod: "C00001" },
         { $eq: [{ "$year": "$creation_date" }, 2019] }
      ]
   }
})
```

If no, then store date values properly as `Date` objects rather than strings.

If you insist to use string values (although this is a poor design) try this one:

```
db.collection.find({
   customer_cod: "C00001",
   creation_date: { $regex: /2019/ }
})
```

Note, `{ customer_cod: "C00001" }`  is equivalent to `{ customer_cod: { $eq: "C00001" } }`.

Comment: OK, thanks I'll switch my design. I'm a noob on nosql db and it is always good to listen advices

Comment: Storing *date/time* values as string is also common for SQL newbies. Here on SO you face it almost every day - and even worse when you store just 2 digit years.